# How to configure H2 database queries to ignore trailing whitespace?

Tags: spring-boot, db2, integration-testing, h2, spring-boot-test

I'm writing some integration tests for my Application and spinning up an H2 in-memory database for the sake of consistency and reproduce-ability for my tests. My organization uses an Oracle DB2 SQL database, and in certain tables, VARCHAR columns are padded with trailing whitespace by other applications.

In my Spring Repository methods, such as `findByDescription(String description)`, the generated SQL of `where description_column = 'description'` works just fine in DB2. But when the same SQL is run against my H2 replica of the database, it fails because of the trailing whitespace. To fix it in H2, I had to modify the repository method to be `findByDescriptionStartsWith(String description)` which generates `where description_column like 'description%'`.

It seems that DB2 is designed to ignore trailing whitespace when running a `where x = 'text'` clause. Is there a way to configure H2 to behave the same way?

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=DB2;preserveWhitespace=true
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.data=classpath:import-x.sql,classpath:import-y.sql,classpath:import-z.sql
```

I considered trimming trailing whitespace out of all my SQL import statements, but that would make for a less valuable integration test, since my H2 database wouldn't be a true replica of my database. Some business logic in my app demands trimming whitespace from VARCHAR columns before rendering a response, so I wouldn't be able to test that, for example, if the H2 database didn't have any whitespace to trim.

Comment: h2 will only add spaces if the column is defined as `char(x)`. If those are `varchar` columns, then your application stored the trailing whitespaces.

Comment: Defining the column as CHAR, which is consistent with my DB2 database column definition, fixed the problem! Thank you!! If you post this as an answer I'll mark it as the solution.